# python buffer size when querying Vertica using Pyodbc

Tags: python, buffer, pyodbc, vertica

i am using pyodbc to connect to Vertica DB and then i am using cursor to execute a query but the results of the query include a text field that is huge, the execute runs but it never returns anything, not even an exception. I can see this when i debug and break point at row=cursor.fetchall() It just comes as empty just like this "[]"

If i try with another dataset with less characters in this huge text field then the execute runs and i get data. I am suspecting it has to do with buffer size when retrieving the data but i don't know. Any suggestions on how to do this? Maybe increase buffer size somehow?

Thanks

```
import requests, pypyodbc, json, pyvertica, pyodbc
from pyvertica import connection
    conn=pyodbc.connect("DSN=HPVertica;UID=muffin;PWD=muffin")
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    query="SELECT field1_int, field2_bigText  FROM someTable WHERE field1_int=103;"

    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
    except Exception as e:
        print('err: {}'.format(e.args[0]))
        print(': {}'.format(e.args[1]))

    row=cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this using pypyodbc instead of pyodbc, no buffer error anymore

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue in pyodbc, at least I am sure I've seen this complained about before and also some random patches.  I just looked at the pyodbc code and it looks like they very recently fixed the issue in [this commit](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/commit/f61c7a45ad427fa89be1d1a0754d3a6ce349b7d1#diff-e3c725deba132806eed477ed5760d5d9) a couple weeks ago.

It doesn't appear to be in the latest (as of this post) tag of 3.0.10.  You'd either have to try the bleeding edge or wait just a little longer for it to be included in a future tag.  (Or patch it yourself based on that commit, I guess).

Comment: Dang, that sucks =( Do you know if there is another library out there that i can use instead of pyodbc?

Comment: You can use [vertica-python](https://github.com/uber/vertica-python) by Uber.  I have had success with it.

Comment: You could also split your large strings into multiple fields in the select (probably under 4k bytes per field) using substrings or something then concatenate them on the client as a short term work-around.